# Synchronizing shared list variable which serves only for searching? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create search mechanism which is threaded, each search thread goal is to find keyword in shared list.

Below is the example code, so do I need to synchronize the if condition or it is not necessary?

(*I really don't know which part in synchronize brackets will be atomic*)

```
class Search extends Thread {

    private ArrayList<String> searchObject;
    private String what;
    private String name;
    public Search(String name, String what,ArrayList<String> searchObject) {
        this.name=name;
        this.what=what;
        this.searchObject=searchObject;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<searchObject.size();i++) {
            synchronized (searchObject) {
                if (searchObject.get(i)==what) {
                    System.out.println(name+": "+what+" => "+true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to do some kind of synchronization here.  What you have works if every other thread also synchronizes on the `List`.  You should probably call [`Collections.synchronizedList()'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) on the list as soon as you create it to ensure that this happens.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't mention, but this is a school project, so I just wanted to create something that will have reasonable use of synchronized keyword, so far this is good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only do you need to synchronize around the if block, you also need to synchronize your entire loop as well.  (Which naturally means you won't see any speedup from parallelization.)

Otherwise, you could end up with:

```
//Assume the list is initially of length 1.
for(int i=0;i<searchObject.size();i++) {  //On the first iteration, we check the if condition, and that check passes
//Before we acquire the lock, but after testing the condition, some other thread empties the list
        synchronized (searchObject) {
            if (searchObject.get(i)==what) {
//Whoops, we just called get(0) on a list with no contents - IndexOutOfBoundsException!
                System.out.println(name+": "+what+" => "+true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or, equally worrying: if the item you're looking for is at index `X` initially, someone could remove items from the list when you release the lock after index `X-1` - meaning your search will fail to find the thing it's looking for, even though it was in the list the entire time.

Of course, those both only apply if there's a chance your `searchObject` will be modified after the creation of your Thread.  If you are *absolutely certain* the `List` will *never* be modified after it's used to construct your `Search` class, then you don't need any synchronization at all.

Comment: Yeah, the list will never be modified,,, i was worried about get(i), but after reading again(and as you mentioned), i realized that there is no need for synchronization, thanks for the clarifying!